# Why do my aspx pages never load when I point my 2.0 application to a remote SQL server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm VPNed into the office which has a SQL Server.  I'm running IIS 7 on my local machine (at home) to serve an asp.net 2.0 web application.  If I put localhost as the my db server, aspx pages load fine (but no db connectivity since I'm not running SQL Server).   If I point to the remote server, my app never loads.  Even pages that don't require db connectivity!

This project works fine when I'm at the office.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: When you say the "my app never loads" do you mean that the start page is never displayed and the processing indicator on the web page keeps spinning, or you get a blank page, or you get a basic looking page with no data on it, or something else?

Comment: Oh, and Management Studio Express Connects just fine to the remote server (important point).

Answer (score 0):

If it's a connectivity problem with the db, you'd eventually get a timeout exception. Does the app test the db connection in a master page, or global.asax? That might explain the wait on non-db-connected pages.

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily get a timeout. You can set the connections to wait forever. But good thought; it's not likely he's done this.

Answer (score 0):

- **Option 1**

You're using a trusted connection for management studio, which means you're connecting via the user account you used to authenticate the vpn.

Your asp.net pages do not run via your user account. They run as Network Service or something similar, and so the trusted connection fails.

- **Option 2**

The VPN is causing an IP conflict somewhere between the local and remote network, and so your http request to view the page doesn't know where to go.

Comment: No, my VPN connection doesn't come with any ActiveDirectory stuff.  I log into the db using regular credentials (with both my app and Mgmt Studio).
If VPN is causing IP conflict, why does Management Studio connect without a hitch?

Comment: Because it's not the database connection that's causing your problem.  It's the http request for the page from your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Might be something specific between openVPN and SQL Server.

See [here](http://openvpn.net/archive/openvpn-users/2007-06/msg00129.html).

Comment: No, I don't think this is the same issue.